# IF Condition Perform Query, Else Perform Other Query

Tags: mysql

It feels pretty straightforward in anything but MySQL.

Basically I need to switch what type of index I am using along with a few other conditions based on how many results a particular term returns.

Something to the effect of:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE term LIKE "term") > 4000
   EXECUTE QUERY A
ELSE
   EXECUTE QUERY B
```

Is this possible in a MySQL statement?

EDIT:

**Query A:**

```
SELECT id 
FROM table_a
FORCE INDEX(id)
JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.id
WHERE term LIKE "term"
ORDER BY date
LIMIT 100;
```

**Query B:**

```
SELECT id 
FROM table_a
FORCE INDEX(term)
JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.id
WHERE term LIKE "term"
GROUP BY term    # These lines would be included for a few conditions not mentioned above.. but are necessary
HAVING COUNT = 1 # same...  
ORDER BY date
LIMIT 100;
```

The reason for the query switch is I get dramatically different result times based on the popularity of the "term".

Comment: What are `QUERY A` and `QUERY B` specifically? SQL typically allows this situation to be handled with a creative `WHERE` clause, but we can't say unless we know if A & B are sufficiently related.

Comment: ...Otherwise, MySQL only permits the use of flow control logic in functions, triggers, & stored procedures -- not in regular queries.

Comment: In theory - yes (with a help of `CASE` statement and joins), but it depends on whether number of fields and records in both queries match. You should post those two along with test data, so that we can answer.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I added the queries to the question.

Comment: you could execute both query A and B and then use a CASE for the count. if that doesn't work, look for stored procedures

Comment: @juuga, the reason for the switch is one query could take either .03 seconds or 17 seconds depending on the index used and whether I add the GROUP BY statement.  I feel like performing them both would be hard on the system.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**EDIT:** What I said below about requiring a stored procedure is NOT TRUE. Try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE term LIKE "term") > 4000 )
    THEN <QUERY A>
    ELSE <QUERY B>
END
```

This is, indeed, a case expression, and it works fine outside a stored proc :-)

For instance:

```
mysql> SELECT CASE WHEN ( 5 > 4 ) THEN ( SELECT 'foo' ) ELSE ( SELECT 'bar' ) END;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CASE WHEN ( 5 > 4 ) THEN ( SELECT 'foo' ) ELSE ( SELECT 'bar' ) END |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| foo                                                                 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT CASE WHEN ( 3 > 4 ) THEN ( SELECT 'foo' ) ELSE ( SELECT 'bar' ) END;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CASE WHEN ( 3 > 4 ) THEN ( SELECT 'foo' ) ELSE ( SELECT 'bar' ) END |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| bar                                                                 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

*Old answer below for historical interest, since it already gather upvotes:*

You can use the below I think, but only inside a stored procedure:

```
CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE term LIKE "term") > 4000
    WHEN 1 THEN <QUERY A>
    ELSE <QUERY B>
END CASE
```

This is a `CASE` statement, as distinct from a `CASE` expression... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html has more gory details.

Actually, I suspect in general if you want to execute different queries conditionally, you're going to need to look toward stored procedures -- I could be wrong, but that's my gut feeling at this point. If you can do it, it'll probably be with CASE expressions!

One last edit: in any real world example, I'd probably do the conditional bit in my application, and just hand off to SQL (or to an ORM which would generate my SQL) once I'd decided what to search for.

Comment: You probably should also mention that this works only when the queries return only 1 row. Otherwise you'll get an error stating that the subquery returns more than 1 row.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
select coalesce(i.id, t.id) id
from (SELECT COUNT(*) countterm FROM table WHERE term LIKE "term") c
left join
     (SELECT id, date
      FROM table_a
      FORCE INDEX(id)
      JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.id
      WHERE term LIKE "term") i on countterm > 4000
left join
     (SELECT id, date
      FROM table_a
      FORCE INDEX(term)
      JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.id
      WHERE term LIKE "term"
      GROUP BY term
      HAVING COUNT = 1) t on countterm <= 4000
ORDER BY coalesce(i.date, t.date)
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: I like this in that it gives the correct output, but it executes both queries and I'm sure OP wants to avoid that.

Comment: @Bohemian: Will it actually execute the sub-query if the `join ... on` (to the main query) condition is false?

Comment: I would think so, because the ON condition is a mini where clause - a filter - for the joined rows, and the false-ness of the condition can not be optimized out (no way to know beforehand that it will be false). I could be wrong...

Comment: @MarkBannister, I had some success with the above answer, however, thank you greatly for taking the time to provide a solution.