# Conditional statements and multiple queries in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL (both instances of phpmyadmin and MySQL workbench) I would like to check if a value exists in a table before I perform any other additional queries to the same table or other tables and below are the sets of queries I have tried but neither are working and both give errors, am new to forming complex queries so kindly ignore any syntax errors I must have made while forming this queries

Query 1

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ( (SELECT * FROM likes WHERE face_id = 'mm' AND phone_id = 'pp') > 1 )
THEN ( SELECT CASE WHEN ( (SELECT * FROM dislikes WHERE face_id = 'mm' AND phone_id = 'pp') > 1) 
   THEN  ( DELETE FROM likes WHERE face_id = 'mm' AND phone_id = 'pp' )
   ELSE  SELECT * FROM likes
   END
 )
ELSE INSERT INTO likes (face_id, phone_id) VALUES ('mm', 'pp')
END
```

Query 2

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM likes WHERE face_id = 'mm' AND phone_id = 'pp')
 IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM dislikes WHERE face_id = 'mm' AND phone_id = 'pp')
  DELETE FROM likes WHERE face_id = 'mm' AND phone_id = 'pp'
 ELSE
   SELECT * FROM likes
ELSE/*Else of first IF*/
INSERT INTO likes (face_id, phone_id) VALUES ('mm', 'pp')
END
```

I got both my choice of queries from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199604/if-condition-perform-query-else-perform-other-query) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072140/using-if-else-statement-based-on-count-to-execute-different-insert-statements)

I have 2 tables, likes and dislikes; both tables have three fields id, face_id and phone_id. Data/Values entering into the likes table must not be present in the dislikes table thus if for instance I wish to insert some values into the likes table, I would check if those values are not present in my likes table and then insert my values and return `true` but if it is present I would check if somehow it is also present in the dislikes table and if it is, I would delete it from the dislikes table, if not, nothing should happen.

Comment: Can you please provide your table definitions, sample data and the expected output? This code looks fairly complex and I suspect there's a simpler way to do what you want.

Comment: Why don't you combine those 2 tables into 1 and add a fourth column? A boolean that's true when it's a like, everything else is a dislike. Or where the fourth column is an enum with either LIKE or DISLIKE. Next you create a unique constraint on the first three fields.

Comment: Hi, I may be wrong. But generally speaking you can't perform an update, Insert or Delete when running a normal query.  Depending on what technology you're working with you may need to do this in a different way. In oracle I would do something in PL/SQL to perform this kind of operation.

Comment: @MichaëlBenjaminSaerens I like your idea on combining the tables, and if combined please show me what the query would then look like.

Comment: @MichaëlBenjaminSaerens I combine the tables and i tried this `SELECT CASE WHEN ( (SELECT * FROM expressions WHERE face_id = 'mm' AND phone_id = 'pp') = 1 )
THEN UPDATE expressions  SET expression = 1 WHERE  face_id = 'mm' AND phone_id = 'pp'
ELSE INSERT INTO expressions (face_id, phone_id, expression) VALUES ('mm', 'pp', 1)
END` but no luck, gives an error @Fudztown could you jelp out here. Thanks

Comment: @DaviesTobialex: What error do you get specifically?

Comment: @Fudztown This is the error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE expressions SET expression = 1 WHERE face_id = 'mm' AND phone_id = 'pp' E' at line 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated you can't perform an update, Insert or Delete when running a normal query, thus it would have to be a stored procedure in my database and i created one like so

```
BEGIN
IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM expressions WHERE face_id = face_id_ AND phone_id = phone_id_ = 1 )
THEN UPDATE expressions SET expression = express_ WHERE face_id = face_id_ AND phone_id = phone_id_;
ELSE INSERT INTO expressions (face_id, phone_id, expression) VALUES (face_id_, phone_id_, express_);
END IF;
END
```

and then called it in my query like so using PDO

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
call update_expressions(:pid, :fid, :exp);
```

Answer (score 0):

No much to go on here. But what about the following?

```
/*Two queries*/
DELETE FROM LIKES
  WHERE FACE_ID IN (SELECT FACE_ID
                      FROM LIKES a, DISLIKES b
                     WHERE     FACE_ID = 'mm'
                           AND PHONE_ID = 'pp'
                           AND a.FACE_ID = b.FACE_ID
                           AND a.PHONE_ID = b.PHONE_ID)
/
/*All likes that are not in likes*/
INSERT INTO LIKES 
SELECT FACE_ID, PHONE_ID FROM DISLIKES
MINUS
SELECT FACE_ID, PHONE_ID FROM LIKES
```