# Is there any way to execute a SELECT only if a condition in a different table is met?

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to do that in a single query? Or do I have to manage it externally? It is not a JOIN of any kind.

```
SELECT
IF (
    (SELECT indicator FROM configuration_table) = 1,
    (SELECT series_id FROM series_table LIMIT 1),
    ''
) as if_exp
FROM
    series_table
```

This executes but returns the first ID over and over, and if I take out the LIMIT 1, it doesn't work as it expects only one result. But what I need is that, if this condition is met:

```
(SELECT indicator FROM configuration_table) = 1,
```

Then I need all this data returned:

```
SELECT series_id, series_code, series_name FROM series_table
```

Is it possible somehow? Should I be doing two queries and managing the data from php? Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IF Condition Perform Query, Else Perform Other Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199604/if-condition-perform-query-else-perform-other-query)

Comment: I didn't see that question, sorry!! Still I don't manage to make it work with the answers in that question...

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be:

```
IF ((SELECT indicator FROM configuration_table) = 1) THEN
    SELECT series_id, series_code, series_name FROM series_table
END IF
```

You did not show us what to do, when the condition is false. We do not know the relationship between `configuration_table` and `series_table`, so we can't find a way to make it in a single query.

Comment: It is not allowing me to start the query with an IF. 

Answering your question, if the condition is false I don't care much about what it does, whatever I can use to identify the condition wasn't met.

Comment: Because you can only execute `IF-ELSE` statements inside a `stored procedure`. You can create one, put inside the query I posted, and execute it. Just drop the stored procedure if you're done.

Answer (score 1):

I have copied this answer from [IF Condition Perform Query, Else Perform Other Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199604/if-condition-perform-query-else-perform-other-query) this answer.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ( (SELECT indicator FROM configuration_table) = 1 )
  THEN 
    SELECT series_id, series_code, series_name FROM series_table
  ELSE 
    <QUERY B>
END
```

Here `Query B` should replaced by your desired query.

Comment: I don't know if I am doing something wrong, but it gives me an error at the SELECT right after THEN. I tried putting the SELECT statement inside parenthesis, but it keeps returning an error at that line (and I have checked the previous parenthesis too).

Comment: A comment I had was causing the error, but after I took it out, it happened as in my query: it only allows `SELECT series_id, series_code, series_name FROM series_table` to return one column and one row, otherwise it returns an error.