# How to update one table from two others depending on fields in all three in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I try to merge data from one table to another table, and need to retrieve data from a third table to do that. How do I insert data in T3, from T2,dependent on data in T1?

I have three tables:

> **T1**: pd_id, default_cat_id, article
>   **T2**: id_category, art_no, origin_desc, origin_code, origin_ref
>   **T3**: pd_id, id_lang, new_desc, new_code, new_ref

T3 needs to be updated, in specific fields in the columns: new_desc, new_code, new_ref:

- with data from fields from T2: origin_desc, origin_code, origin_ref
- where t2.art_no matches t1.article AND t2.id_category matches t1.default_cat_id
- AND this only where t1.pd_id matches t3.pd_id AND t3.id_lang is equal '2'.

Illustrated in image:
[T1, T2, T3 and the desired result in T3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqo8y.png)

I tried serveral things with JOINS but can't get it.

```
MySQL
UPDATE t3 
INNER JOIN t1 ON (
    t1.article=t2.art_no 
    AND t1.default_cat_id=t2.id_category 
    AND t1.pd_id=t3.pd_id
)
INNER JOIN t2 ON (
    t2.origin_desc=t3.new_desc
    AND t2.origin_code=t3.new_code
    AND t2.origin_ref=t3.new_ref
    AND t2.art_no=t1.article
    AND t2.id_category=t1.default_cat_id
)
SET 
t2.origin_desc=t3.new_desc,
t2.origin_code=t3.new_code,
t2.origin_ref=t3.new_ref
WHERE
t2.art_no=t1.article 
AND t2.id_category=t1.default_cat_id 
AND t3.id_lang=2;
```

> #1054 - Unknown column 't2.art_no' in table on clause

Comment: you need to use SELECT CASE, this answer could point you in thhe right direction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199604/if-condition-perform-query-else-perform-other-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing some strange joins here.
At the beginning you are joining `t3` with `t1`, but the `ON` clause contains:

```
t1.article=t2.art_no 
AND t1.default_cat_id=t2.id_category
```

`t2.art_no` and `t2.id_category` do not exist at this point of the statement because `t2` does not exist yet.
It will be introduced later but at this point it does not exist.
So you can't use `t2` yet neither its columns.
Maybe remove these lines, because I see that they exist also in the `WHERE` clause.
Also you say that you want to update the table `t3`, but these lines:

```
SET 
t2.origin_desc=t3.new_desc,
t2.origin_code=t3.new_code,
t2.origin_ref=t3.new_ref
```

update the columns of table t2.
Should they be:

```
SET 
t3.new_desc=t2.origin_desc,
t3.new_code=t2.origin_code,
t3.new_ref=t2.origin_ref
```

or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @forpas -this was a hint in the right direction.

I have trimmed the code now, and it worked, and looks now so:

```
MySQL
UPDATE t3 
INNER JOIN t1 ON (
    t1.pd_id=t3.pd_id
)
INNER JOIN t2 ON(
t2.art_no=t1.article
)
SET 
t3.new_desc=t2.origin_desc,
t3.new_code=t2.origin_code,
t3.new_ref=t2.origin_ref
WHERE
t2.id_category=t1.default_cat_id 
AND t3.id_lang=2;
```